# Pipe not renaming fields

Tags: json, yahoo-pipes

I have a [JSON feed](https://www.waterconnect.sa.gov.au/_layouts/WMTV/Data.ashx/GridSitesLatest?AppID=AMLR,EP,KI,NY,RMW,SAAL,SAMDB,SE&Period=&Date=&Time=&MonType=&_=1399328432876) that I want to rename some of the fields and output a new JSON feed.

Here is one of the nodes on the source JSON feed:

```
{
       "SiteId": "A2390506",
       "SiteName": "Blackford Drain",
       "SubRegion": "Blackford Drain",
       "SubRegionID": 38,
       "ResultDate": "28/08/14 15:00",
       "10.00": 0.0,
       "100.00": 1.293,
       "151.00": 4.8747,
       "821.00": 13501.0
},
```

Its those latter fields that are labelled as floats (10.00, 100.00, etc) that I want to change to more meaningful names.

I thought this could be quite easily achieved [with a Pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=f4652fa2080bfd796cbe287000b7148a) and a Rename Operator.
I can rename any of the fields that have string names, but not the latter fields.

[image]

Have I done something wrong, or is this a limitation of the rename operator? Any ideas on a workaround?

[The source of the pipe is here.](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=f4652fa2080bfd796cbe287000b7148a)

**--EDIT**
Should also point out that I have also tried *'item.100.00'* which also fails to rename.

Comment: That's nasty. Looks like a bug. But the JSON is very strange too. I played with this for a while but couldn't figure out.

Comment: I think the main problem is the key in the item has a dot. If you specify item._00.00, it actually looks for item['_00]'['00'].

Comment: @wbinglee do you concurr that this could be a potential limitation of YahooPipes then?  (THanks for the info)

Comment: @Simon y, I think it may be the limitation of yahoo pipes.

Comment: Can anyone suggest another tool in YP that could perhaps search and replace the . or somehow workaround this issue?